# Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes in Ionic without duplicates

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to implement the Facebook Plugin in my Ionic App together with this plugins:

```
com.ionic.keyboard 1.0.4 "Keyboard"
com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin 2.5.0 "PushPlugin"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.2 "Console"
cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview 1.4.0 "Crosswalk WebView Engine"
cordova-plugin-datepicker 0.9.2 "DatePicker"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.0 "Device"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 3.0.0 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.0.0 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.0 "Whitelist"
de.appplant.cordova.common.registerusernotificationsettings 1.0.1 "RegisterUserNotificationSettings"
de.appplant.cordova.plugin.badge 0.7.1 "Cordova Badge Plugin"
org.apache.cordova.geolocation 0.3.12 "Geolocation"
phonegap-facebook-plugin 0.12.0 "Facebook Connect"
```

I keep getting this error when doing `ionic run android --device`
[image]

I've checked and i cannot find duplicates of android-support-v4.jar neither in platform/android/libs nor in the other plugin folders

Answer (score 0):

I see you have phonegap-facebook-plugin. This was a problem for me - it added an additional android-jar-v4.zip folder to my project. Switching to [cordova-plugin-facebook4](https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4) might help.